# How to write a script to click certain image links?

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm trying to open all links on a webpage, where the code for each link is approximately the following:

```
<a href="/tor/download.php/*jibberish_letters*" id="dlLink137836"><img border="0" src="/pic/down.png" alt="Download" title="Download"></a>
```

The script I'm currently attempting to use is the following, but I only get an 'undefined' error when I try to run it.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[title="Download"]');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
 window.open(links[i].href,"_blank");
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Your sample `a` tag doesn't have a title attribute but the image `does`. Any popup blockers installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('img[title="Download"]');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    window.open(links[i].parentNode.href,"_blank");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the attribute `title="Download"` isn't in the `a` tag, but in the `img` tag. This should works:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a img[title="Download"]');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vDtqY/)

But as @Nicolae suggested, the pop-up blocker blocks it, at least in my browser(Chrome) it happened. Furthermore, is a strange pratice, indeed.